# How to avoid repetition

Tags: style

How do you avoid too much repetition both in writing and speech? I feel like I'm repeating the same word over and over again when I'm writing or talking to people.

> The **price** of this **tablet** is X and the **price** of that **tablet** is Y.

In this example, I feel like I'm repeating "price" and "tablet" too much. I even feel like I'm repeating the same sentence construction. Is there a shorter/better way to say this?

> X is **being sold in that store** at $200 and Y is **being sold in that store** at $300.

If the two "that store" are referring to the same store, what kind of information can I delete without losing too much information?

> Styluses X are $3 **per dozen** and styluses Y are $4 **per dozen**.

In this example, I'm not sure if I can leave out the second "per dozen" and still convey the same meaning.

> Styluses X are $3 **per dozen** and styluses Y are $4 **(per dozen is implied?)**.

Or should I even do this to avoid repeating the same construction?

> Styluses X are $3 if **ordered in dozens** and styluses Y are $4 if **ordered by the dozen**.

I tried to change things around a bit but I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: You can always look for alternative words in a **thesaurus**, which are designed specifically to solve this problem.

Comment: Put the two subjects together to make one clause. For example: "The price of X Tablet and Y tablet is $120.00 and $140.00 **respectively**".

Comment: Two points: (1) Such repitition isn't always bad. In fact, there's [even a name for it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(rhetoric)). (2) If the paralleism does sound awkward or repititious, that's not necessarily a bad thing, either. Few people write eloquently on the first draft. Therefore, when writing, the answer to your question is often "proofread & edit." When speaking, most listeners won't hold you accountable for repeating the same words or phrases. Incidentally, in your stylus example, I like your original sentence best.

Comment: This is not the type of repetition that's unwanted in fiction, such as "She said... She did... She stood up... She sat down...", this is repetition for the sake of clarity. Per dozen is not necessarily implied, and if you lose it you risk ambiguity. Also, it greatly depends what you write for. If it's fiction, then spicing it up might be good. But if it's a catalogue, price list or a manual, dry but clear might be better. With that said, I don't see why first sentence can't be "The price of this tablet is X and of that one is Y."

Answer (score 6):

Put the two subjects together to make one clause.

For example:

> "The prices of X tablet **and** Y tablet are $120.00 and $140.00
>   **respectively**"

Join the two subjects with "both" and use a different preposition:

> "X and Y **are both** sold in that store **for** $200.00 and $300.00"

Sometimes for clarity's sake you might need to repeat the same expression but adding "while" as a conjunction makes the sentence flow more smoothly.

> Stylus X are $3 per dozen **while** stylus Y are $4 per dozen.

You could swap the clauses:

> **If ordered by the dozen** stylus X **is** $3 and stylus Y is $4

I changed the plural noun *styluses* to the singular *stylus* because I presume each stylus has a different price tag, but if company X sells several different styluses all at the same price than it's perfectly correct to keep the plural form.

EDIT:

Suggestion No 2 seems open to misinterpretations, so here are other alternatives.

If X and Y are priced identically:

> "X and Y **are both** sold in that store **for** $200.00

But if not:

> "X and Y are sold in that store **for** $200.00 and $300.00 **respectively**.

and

> X **is** $200.00 and Y **is** $300.00 sold in that store.

Comment: There is some really good advice in here for the _stylus_ sentence. +1

Comment: There needs to be a comma after "X and Y are both sold"; otherwise you are claiming that there are two prices for each.

Comment: I'm not the greatest with punctuation, admittedly, but why would X and Y each have two different prices? Are they not two different products on sale with two distinct prices? X=$200.00 and Y=$300.00
I suppose if X and Y had the *same* price tag then my suggestion could stand but I'm not sure adding the comma would remove the ambiguity (which I'm struggling to see).
Perhaps this is a case when repetition is required in order to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: FWIW, I'd put the comma after _store_, and I'd use the word _respectively_ at the end again. I think @StoneyB means, as is, the sentence could be parsed to mean, "X is sold in that store for $200 and $300, and Y is sold in that store for $200 and $300." Admittedly, that doesn't make too much sense (unless both X and Y have both basic and deluxe models, in which case it might make sense after all). But I don't see how a single comma w/out "respectively" solves that potential misinterpretation.

Comment: No comma, omit *both* (as StoneyB explains), and add *respectively*: "X and Y are sold in that store for $200 and $300 respectively." The comma doesn't add anything. These aren't clauses and no pause is required.

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you gave, I don't think the repetition is bad at all. These are parallel constructions and repetition makes that clear. You can and should repeat words when your intent is to show that two things are similar.

Contrast your examples with a sentence like, "Bob decided he needed a new tablet. So he went to a store that sells tablets where the tablet salesman showed him a variety of tablets. He particularly liked tablet XR-17, but tablet Ultra Foo, a tablet made by Acme, was cheaper. ..." Here the repetition of "tablet" is distracting and it would be a good idea to look for alternative phrasing.

Others have mentioned substituting synonyms. I assume by "tablet" here you mean tablet computers and by "stylus" you mean styluses used with computer screens. If not, the same ideas apply though the details would be different. But in that case I don't know of any synonyms, though you could use more general terms. In context a general term could pretty unambiguously refer to a specific item. Like if you're talking about tablets and then instead of saying "tablet XR-17" you say "model XR-17", the reader would generally assume this was a model of tablet and not a car or a toaster. In other cases you could drop the word completely as it's already been established by context. Like the above paragraph could be reworded to, "Bob decided he needed a new tablet. So he went to a store that sells computers where the salesman showed him a variety of models. He particularly liked the XR-17, but the Ultra Foo by Acme was cheaper ..."

But in your examples, substituting synonyms could create ambiguity. Like if instead of "The price of this tablet is X and the price of that tablet is Y" you wrote, say, "The price of this tablet is $200 and the cost of that computer is $300", a reader might well wonder if your switch from "price" to "cost" was simply to avoid repetition or if you are trying to convey a different meaning. Similarly they might wonder if the second item is also a tablet or if it is some other kind of computer.

Answer (score 0):

Mari-Lou A gave many good ways to do it. Let me just add about using em-dash to replace repeating part.

> The price of this tablet is X, and that — Y.
>
> X is being sold in that store at $200 and Y — in that one, at $300.
>
> Styluses X are $3 per dozen and styluses Y — $4.

And no, in your case:

> Styluses X are $3 per dozen and styluses Y are $4 (per dozen is implied?).

No, the second "per dozen" is not implied - specifically because you alliterate "styluses Y are $4" which is not the same as the prior clause at all. If you use the em-dash omission, the dash means "the same as before" and then the dozen actually is implied.

Comment: Sorry, but "gave *most of* good ways"? Is that standard AmEng?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I think there is a missing "the" there; omitted inadvertantly.

Comment: @J.R. *"gave most of the good ways"*? It sounds a bit better but still very odd to my ears.

Comment: I'd say "many good ways." *Most* implies a finite list.

Comment: Thanks all; I'm still struggling with some English constructs... :)